# android making folder and all its subdirectory undeletable

Tags: android

i want to make and folder and all directory undeletable by user:

basically my app has large files and i want to play it from external sd card now problem is that most user delets them by mistake how can i prevent it

i also tried hiding foler by giving prefix . but its now working i name file .myfile but still i am able to view this file any idea ???..

Answer (score -1):

Rather than populating a folder on the user's device, you could use an expansion file. http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html

Comment: will not prefer file expansion and download time will be large , will give content to user in sd card